# Can't install and run Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I’m new to Kubuntu, and in fact to Linux.
I particularly wish to run Kubuntu to use FFmpeg with Nvidia Hardware acceleration.

I have a Desktop computer with several hard discs including SSD and conventional SATA drives.  One SSD M2 has Windows 10 installed.
I have managed to install Ubuntu on an SSD and this runs but I’m having trouble completing the FFmpeg Nvidia instructions.

I made a USB stick using Rufus of Kubuntu version 20.10.  This failed to install, and came up with a ‘known’ error which I now can’t remember but I’ll try to install it again if it helps the solution.
I then used the same USB stick to install version 20.04.2 LTS.  This installed (according to the installer).
When I reset the computer and went to the boot menu, the version is showing, but surprisingly it shows my Windows 10 drive beside the name.  When I try to run version 20.04.2 LTS I get ‘GNU Grub version 2.04’ some text about TAB listing commands, and a prompt.

Can anyone help with this, please?
Derek Clements

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1316885/edit) to attach a readable picture or clearly describe your choices in the GRUB menu. We cannot see what you are seeing, so please help us to help you.

Comment: *"this failed to install, and came up with a ‘known’ error which I now can’t remember"* You're going to need to provide that error. There can be literally 1,000's of reasons why an installation failures.